# Bypassing bastion idle timeout : Session stopped

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm forced to work through bastion to connect to the servers I work on.
that's fine but the idle timeout is ridiculously small and it totally ignores the ssh keep alive of the client.
I can't change bastion's configuration as it's not my team's scope.

So.. How can I bypass this limitation ?

Could I send some ghost command that does nothing but are considered as an activity with my ssh client ( mobaxterm, but not fixed on one client could use any other one ) ?

I can configure some macro with moba.. but what could I send, I looked for bash command like ctrl + y .. but they all 'do' something.

Glad for any input !

For clarity I ssh to the remote machine this way :
remote server is the bastion server

username contains the remote server I wish to log into and some user information needed too

login : final_user@some_other_user1@remote_server:SSH:some_other_user2

I get a "Session Stopped" if I exceed the timeout, not even a real timeout..

Comment: Please read [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585887/108618). Since you tried `ServerAlive*` (right?), it's either something like Bash's `TMOUT` variable in your remote shell you can configure, or something you cannot configure and need to bypass. What activities do matter? How exactly do you connect to the bastion? Is it something equivalent to `ssh -N` (with port forwarding) or `ssh -J`? Or is it something that actually gives you an interactive shell on the bastion? Are you sure it's the bastion that disconnects you, not the target system? Have you tried to talk to the admin?

Comment: thx for answering, I added the details of how I do login with bastion, I can have an interactive shell on bastion too with a menu with the list of machines on which I have permission to login, yes the serveralive is configured on the remote server but I think the one that matters must be on the bastion gateway ? I had no disconnection before bastion when I connected directly on the server, but the security policy does not allow that anymore. I have not yet talked to the admin but quite pessimist on the fact he'll allow more idle time. I dunno which activites really matter, shell actions, vim..

Comment: "yes the serveralive is configured on the remote server" – Not that it matters much in your case (I guess), but `ServerAlive*` options belong to the configuration of the client, while `ClientAlive*` options belong to the configuration of the server.